# Debian Realtek RTL7832BS driver

Tags: debian, drivers, make, gcc

I recently installed Linux Debian on my Lark Ultimate 7i WIN tablet, that was originally running windows, but Windows was so much laggy on this device.
I succesfully installed Debian with LXDE, that was running beautifully on this device, with almost no cpu usage and no ram usage. But I ran into a problem with internet connection.

I went to [this site](http://driveragent.com/c/driveragent_results?uid=16226867137942), and I got that the device is using REALTEK RTL7832BS chipset. I searched almost entire internet for results, but nothing worked for me. I only found [this driver](https://github.com/hadess/rtl8723bs.git) to work for some guy over the world.
I successfully installed `build-essential` package on my system using computer with internet by porting .deb packages to the tablet. I also ported that driver git package here, and ran `make` inside that driver directory, but I got this output:

```
make: Warning: File 'Makefile' has modification time 88116208 s in the future. 
make ARCH=i386 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/3.16.0-4-686-pae/build M=/home/main/drv/drvWORK modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-686-pae'
make[1]: Warning: File 'Makefile' has modification time 88116208 s in the future. 
make[2]: Warning: File 'Makefile' has modification time 88116208 s in the future. 
Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-686-pae'
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common/scripts/gcc-version.sh: line 25: gcc-4.8: command not found
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common/scripts/gcc-version.sh: line 26: gcc-4.8: command not found
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common/arch/x86/MakeFile:121:stack-protector enabled, but compiler support broken...
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common/Makefile:647: Cannot use CONFIG_CC_STACKPROTECTOR_REGULAR: -fstack-protector...
make[3]: gcc-4.8: Command not found
make[3]: Warning: File 'scripts/Makefile.lib' has modification time 59474584 s in the future.
CC [M] /home/main/drv/drvWORK /core/rtw_cmd.o
/bin/sh: 1: gcc-4.8: not found
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common/scripts/Makefile.build:262: recipe for target '/home/main/drv/drvWORK/core...
failed
make[4]: *** [/home/main/drv/drvWORK/core/rtw_cmd.o] Error 127
Makefile:181: recipe for target 'sub-make' failed
make[2]: *** [sub-make] Error 2
Makefile:8: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-686-pae'
Makefile:216: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: **** [modules] Error 2
```

Additional info: 
---Core: Intel Atom 
---CPU Architecture: i386 (x32/x86)

Comment: a) patches needed for the current kernel according to README.
b) you have no gcc-4.8 installed.

Comment: Yes I know, I already updated my kernel to 4.0 and there is much less errors, only one that I have installed gcc 4.9 not 4.8

Comment: You have to patch the kernel, not just install from a binary package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, solved the problem over time myself. The problem was that you need to install kernel 4.1 or higher OR use a patch for older kernel (I have not tried). Then you must install gcc-4.8 to run make.

**UPDATE 2018:**

Debian stable now includes kernel 4.9, and backports includes 4.16, which is relatively recent, so the problem can be solved quite easily. The RTL8723BS was merged into mainline in 4.12.

**UPDATE 2020:**
The rtl8723bs kernel driver is included in the mainline kernel together with the matching bluetooth drive rtl8723bs-bt. Everything works out-of-the-box in Debian 10 (you may still need to copy the firmware files though).